# C++ weird output with printf

Tags: c++, c

Below is my functions, its suppose to list some countries
I tried using << fixed but doesn't seems to help

This is my output:

```
�ѿra
�ѿd Arab Emirates
�ѿnistan
�ѿua and Barbuda
�ѿlla
�ѿia
�ѿia
�ѿrlands Antilles
�ѿa
�ѿctica
�ѿtina
�ѿcan Samoa
```

My text file is okay, i wonder is there wrong in my casting of data.

This is my CountryData.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "CountryData.h"

using namespace std;
// ====================================================================

void readData ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    NoOfRecordsRead = 0;
    char buffer [Line_Char_Buffer_Size];

    pFile = fopen (INPUT_FILE_NAME , "r");

    if (pFile == NULL) 
        perror ("Error opening file 'Countries.txt' !");
    else
    {
        while ( !feof (pFile) )
        {
            char* aLine = get_line (buffer, Line_Char_Buffer_Size, pFile);

            if (aLine != NULL)
            {
//              printf ("%d] aLine => %s\n", NoOfRecordsRead, aLine);
                globalCountryDataArray [NoOfRecordsRead++] = createCountryRecord (aLine);
            }
        }

     fclose (pFile);

    }
}

// ====================================================================

char* get_line (char *s, size_t n, FILE *f)
{
    char *p = fgets (s, n, f);

    if (p != NULL) 
    {
        size_t last = strlen (s) - 1;
        if (s[last] == '\n') 
            s[last] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}

// ====================================================================

CountryRecordType createCountryRecord (char* aLine)
{
    CountryRecordType ctryRec;
    char* pch = strtok (aLine, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 1) Retrieve TLD
    strcpy (ctryRec.TLD, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 2) Retrieve Country
    strcpy (ctryRec.Country, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 3) Retrieve FIPS104
    strcpy (ctryRec.FIPS104, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 4) Retrieve ISO2
    strcpy (ctryRec.ISO2, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 5) Retrieve ISO3
    strcpy (ctryRec.ISO3, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 6) Retrieve ISONo
    ctryRec.ISONo = atof (pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 7) Retrieve Capital
    strcpy (ctryRec.Capital, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 8) Retrieve Region
    strcpy (ctryRec.Region, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 9) Retrieve Currency
    strcpy (ctryRec.Currency, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 10) Retrieve CurrencyCode
    strcpy (ctryRec.CurrencyCode, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, LINE_DATA_DELIMITER);

    // 11) Retrieve Population
    ctryRec.Population = atof (pch);

    return (ctryRec);

}

// ====================================================================

char* displayRecordContent (CountryRecordType ctryRec)
{
    char * output = ctryRec.Country;
    return output;

}

// ====================================================================

void showAllRecords ()
{
    int i=0;
    string stroutput;
    char * result;
    for (i=0; i<NoOfRecordsRead; i++)
    {

        result = displayRecordContent (globalCountryDataArray [i]);
        stroutput += result;
        stroutput += "\n";
    }

cout << fixed << stroutput << endl;

}

// ====================================================================

int findCountryRecord (const char* countryName)
{
    int idx     = -1;
    int found   = 0;

    while (!found && (++idx < Max_Record_Size))
        if (strcmp (globalCountryDataArray [idx].Country, countryName) == 0)
            found = 1;

    if (found)
        return (idx);
    else
        return (-1);
}

// ====================================================================

char* getCapital (const char* countryName)
{
    int idx = findCountryRecord (countryName);

    if (idx < 0)
    {
        printf ("Country '%s' not found!\n", countryName);
        return (NULL);  
    }
    else
        return (globalCountryDataArray [idx].Capital);
}

// ====================================================================

char* getCurrencyCode (const char* countryName)
{
    int idx = findCountryRecord (countryName);

    if (idx < 0)
    {
        printf ("Country '%s' not found!\n", countryName);
        return (NULL);  
    }
    else
        return (globalCountryDataArray [idx].CurrencyCode);
}


// ====================================================================

main ()
{
    readData ();
    showAllRecords ();


}
```

This is my CountryData.h file

```
#ifndef COUNTRY_DATA_H
#define COUNTRY_DATA_H

// ====================================================================

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
// ====================================================================

#define TLD_LEN             2
#define COUNTRY_LEN         100
#define FIPS104_LEN         2
#define ISO2_LEN            2
#define ISO3_LEN            3
#define CAPITAL_LEN         100
#define REGION_LEN          100
#define CURRENCY_LEN        50
#define CURRENCY_CODE_LEN   3

#define No_Of_Rec_Fields        11
#define Max_Record_Size         250
#define Line_Char_Buffer_Size   400

#define LINE_DATA_DELIMITER     ","
#define INPUT_FILE_NAME         "Countries.txt"

// ====================================================================

//const char*   LINE_DATA_DELIMITER     = ",";
//const char*   INPUT_FILE_NAME         = "Countries.txt";


typedef struct CountryRecord
{
    char TLD            [TLD_LEN+1];            // Top Level Domain code
    char Country        [COUNTRY_LEN+1];    
    char FIPS104        [FIPS104_LEN+1];        // Ctry code according to FIPS104 standard
    char ISO2           [ISO2_LEN+1];           // Ctry code according to ISO2    standard
    char ISO3           [ISO3_LEN+1];           // Ctry code according to ISO3    standard
    double ISONo;

    char Capital        [CAPITAL_LEN+1];    
    char Region         [REGION_LEN+1];         // E.g. Asia, Europe, etc.
    char Currency       [CURRENCY_LEN+1];       // Full name of currency
    char CurrencyCode   [CURRENCY_CODE_LEN+1];  // Currency abbreviation
    double Population;

}   CountryRecordType;

int NoOfRecordsRead;
CountryRecordType globalCountryDataArray [Max_Record_Size];

// ====================================================================

void readData ();
char* get_line (char *s, size_t n, FILE *f);
CountryRecordType createCountryRecord (char* aLine);
char* displayRecordContent (CountryRecordType ctryRec);
void showAllRecords ();

int findCountryRecord (const char* countryName);
char* getCapital (const char* countryName);
char* getCurrencyCode (const char* countryName);

// ====================================================================

#endif // COUNTRY_DATA_H
```

This is part of my countries.txt file

```
AD,Andorra,AN,AD,AND,20.00,Andorra la Vella,Europe,Euro,EUR,67627.00
AE,United Arab Emirates,AE,AE,ARE,784.00,Abu Dhabi,Middle East,UAE Dirham,AED,2407460.00
AF,Afghanistan,AF,AF,AFG,4.00,Kabul,Asia,Afghani,AFA,26813057.00
AG,Antigua and Barbuda,AC,AG,ATG,28.00,Saint John's,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,66970.00
AI,Anguilla,AV,AI,AIA,660.00,The Valley,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,12132.00
AL,Albania,AL,AL,ALB,8.00,Tirana,Europe,Lek,ALL,3510484.00
AM,Armenia,AM,AM,ARM,51.00,Yerevan,Commonwealth of Independent States,Armenian Dram,AMD,3336100.00
AN,Netherlands Antilles,NT,AN,ANT,530.00,Willemstad,Central America and the Caribbean,Netherlands Antillean guilder,ANG,212226.00
AO,Angola,AO,AO,AGO,24.00,Luanda,Africa,Kwanza,AOA,10366031.00
AQ,Antarctica,AY,AQ,ATA,10.00,--,Antarctic Region, , ,0.00
AR,Argentina,AR,AR,ARG,32.00,Buenos Aires,South America,Argentine Peso,ARS,37384816.00
AS,American Samoa,AQ,AS,ASM,16.00,Pago Pago,Oceania,US Dollar,USD,67084.00
AT,Austria,AU,AT,AUT,40.00,Vienna,Europe,Euro,EUR,8150835.00
AU,Australia,AS,AU,AUS,36.00,Canberra,Oceania,Australian dollar,AUD,19357594.00
```

Comment: "My text file is okay" - what's the encoding? How do you read the data?

Comment: What is `CountryRecordType` and how is its `Country` allocated?

Comment: IMO, you need to start by deciding whether you really want to write C or C++, and then do that. Right now, you're trying to combine the two, but mostly ending up (IMO) with a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are passing `CountryRecordType` by value to `displayRecordContent`, the pointer you are returning is invalid, and using it results in undefined behavior. This is because you are returning a pointer to the contents held by the copy that was made during the function call, which gets destructed when the function returns.

Modify your `displayRecordContent` function to use pass by reference instead.

```
const char* displayRecordContent (const CountryRecordType &ctryRec)
{
    const char * output = ctryRec.Country;
    return output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite the code pretty much from the ground up, attempting to actually use C++ instead of C with a few bits of C++ mixed in.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

struct CountryRecord { 
    std::string TLD;
    std::string Country;
    std::string FIPS104;
    std::string ISO2;
    std::string ISO3;
    double ISONo;
    std::string Capital;
    std::string Region;
    std::string Currency;
    std::string CurrencyCode;
    double Population;
};

template <class T>
std::istream &get_field(std::istream &is, T &field) {
    is >> field;
    is.ignore(1);
    return is;
}

template<>
std::istream &get_field<std::string>(std::istream &is, std::string &field) {
    return std::getline(is, field, ',');
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, CountryRecord &r) { 
    get_field(is, r.TLD);
    get_field(is, r.Country);
    get_field(is, r.FIPS104);
    get_field(is, r.ISO2);
    get_field(is, r.ISO3);
    get_field(is, r.ISONo);
    get_field(is, r.Capital);
    get_field(is, r.Region);
    get_field(is, r.Currency);
    get_field(is, r.CurrencyCode);
    return get_field(is, r.Population);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, CountryRecord const &r) { 
    return os << r.Country;
}

int main() { 
    std::ifstream in("countries.txt");
    std::vector<CountryRecord> countries(
        (std::istream_iterator<CountryRecord>(in)),
        std::istream_iterator<CountryRecord>());

    std::copy(countries.begin(), countries.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<CountryRecord>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```